# Word for searching through someone's possessions without permission

Tags: word-request

What word can we use if someone checks, searches or looks through somebody else's possessions without the owner's consent or knowledge? People who do this may not be looking for a specific thing, just something interesting or valuable.

For example:

> When I turned around, I saw somebody was ........... my bag. (Past continuous)
>
> Toddlers like to .............. my wardrobe and bookcase.

Comment: `Perusing` (probably way too casual for what you're talking about), `sifting through`, `digging through`, `going through`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An excellent verb is "[rummage](http://thefreedictionary.com/rummage)". It is typically used with the prepositions "through" and "around" accordingly, or simply with "in".
It should be noted that only the context suggests that "rummage" is without the owner's permission. It does not directly mean that.
Another viable suggestion is "[rifle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rifle)". It is used with the same prepositions as above. This verb **is** more adept to stealing/looking without the owner's permission. Here are some examples to suit your ideas:

> When I turned around, I saw somebody was rummaging through my bag.
>
> My toddler nephews like to rummage around wardrobes and bookcases.
>
> I came home to find a masked man rifling through my stuff.
>
> I couldn't believe my eyes when I saw the security guard rummaging through the piles of suitcases.

**EDIT**
Another option is "[ransack](http://thefreedictionary.com/ransack)" though this carries an air of "pillage" which has an air of violence about it. This is perhaps not the preferred option if you wish to express purely "without the owner's consent/permission".

> We had a call from the police to say the summer house had been ransacked.

Comment: As we're on a *learner's* site, it might be worth noting that relatively speaking, *rummage, rifle, ransack* are all [50-cent words](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/45685/2637). A common "5-cent" expression is *somebody was **poking** [though/around in] my bag*.

Comment: "Snoop" is another good word for this.  It implies a more general investigation, but someone can "snoop around" in your closet, as if they're looking for something specific.

Comment: +1 for “rifle”, which is the word that popped into my mind immediately while reading this question.

Comment: I vote for **rifle** too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - _rummage_ hardly seems like a 50-cent word to me. I wonder if that's an AmE/BrE difference. [Cool Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poking+around%2Crummaging+through&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), too.

Comment: @J.R. I would have thought that another AmE/BrE difference would be the metaphor for "50-cent words" (or "20-dollar words" as I've also heard them called)! /@FumbleFingers Your point is well taken, though, about appropriate vocabulary for learners. It just happens that in AmE, "rummage" and "ransack" are plain words even though they're not common; "rifle" (in this sense) is a little fancier. Good luck to anyone trying to distinguish these degrees of fanciness without years of experience among the natives, though!

Comment: @Murat. If you're going to edit my answer, at least make sure it makes decent sense to do so! Your suggestion of "Toddlers like rummaging around my wardrobe" is pointless and borderline weird!

Comment: @JMB sorry :) is it ok now

Comment: @Murat Almost. I've added in the 3rd person "s".

Comment: @JMB I think your toddler nephews like to rummage around **in** wardrobes, no? I can't imagine there's much of interest on the ground around the wardrobe. :P

Comment: @Catija I reckon toddlers can take an interest in pretty much everything! The preposition "in" is optional here.

Comment: People generally just say stop going through my stuff. I saw him going through my stuff. And as someone else said, you can also say snoop. 'I can see him snooping around my house and going through all my personal stuff, should I call the police?'

Answer (score 11):

The word [snoop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snoop) works well in this case.

> When I turn around, I saw somebody **snooping** in my bag. (Past
>   continuous)
>
> Toddlers like to **snoop through**  wardrobes and bookcases.

The word snoop implies without permission, so I would favor it versus other choices that rely on context.

Comment: Welcome to ell.  Nice answer.  Just so you know, for some reason, this SE site greatly prefers formatting with the ">," as in the original question, rather than the mono-spaced embedded scrollable panel.

Comment: This does a better job of expressing the "without permission" part. I think 'snoop' implies just looking without taking anything, so that might be relevant.

Comment: This was the answer that came immediately to my head.

Comment: Yes, this is better fitting to the context. +1

Answer (score 0):

I shall be leaning toward another word and **not 'rummage'** because it does not happen unbeknownst to the owner.

A better verb that comes to my mind is the verb 'sneak'.

> [sneak](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sneak_1?q=sneak) -*to **do something** or take somebody/something somewhere secretly, **often without permission***

If you *sneak through* something, you are searching through something especially without permission.

---

Note: J.R.'s comment is very useful. Kindly consider it.

Comment: _Sneak_ works, but only if we use a suitable preposition. If a man is _sneaking **by** my bag_, he is walking past it steathily; if a man is _sneaking **with** my bag_, he might be trying to steal it. If he is _sneaking **through** my bag_, though, then that's what the OP is asking about.